# Embedded tomcat not launching

Tags: spring-boot, spring-web

I wanted to upgrade to spring boot 1.5.6 from boot 1.4.3. 
I created a simple web project using the spring initializer and added a simple Controller class. My pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

RestApplication.java

```
package com.djcodes.testing.rest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
  package com.djcodes.testing.rest;


import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {


    @RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, value ="/welcome")
    public String welcome() {
        return "Welcome to employee controller";
    }

}
```

When I try to Launch it doenst start and just builds

```
 $ mvn spring-boot:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building demo-rest-api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ demo-rest-api >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ demo-rest-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ demo-rest-api ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ demo-rest-api ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/dj/Github/test-frameworks-tools/demo-rest-api/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ demo-rest-api ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ demo-rest-api <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE:run (default-cli) @ demo-rest-api ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-08-20 16:53:09.047  INFO 7690 --- [           main] c.djcodes.testing.rest.RestApplication   : Starting RestApplication on lenovo with PID 7690 (/home/dj/Github/test-frameworks-tools/demo-rest-api/target/classes started by dj in /home/dj/Github/test-frameworks-tools/demo-rest-api)
2017-08-20 16:53:09.051  INFO 7690 --- [           main] c.djcodes.testing.rest.RestApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-20 16:53:09.099  INFO 7690 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@72458578: startup date [Sun Aug 20 16:53:09 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-20 16:53:09.762  INFO 7690 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-08-20 16:53:09.772  INFO 7690 --- [           main] c.djcodes.testing.rest.RestApplication   : Started RestApplication in 0.966 seconds (JVM running for 4.05)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.740 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-20T16:53:09+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/275M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-08-20 16:53:09.942  INFO 7690 --- [       Thread-2] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@72458578: startup date [Sun Aug 20 16:53:09 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-20 16:53:09.943  INFO 7690 --- [       Thread-2] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Has something change in spring-boot 1.5.6? Above works fine with 1.4.3

Thanks

Comment: Update: i Change to 1.5.2 and it works .. Guess 1.5.6 has some additional things that needs to be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was spring boot version issues. Worked with 1.5.3.RELASE